# Use specific elements from JSON data and display it on a React page?

Tags: reactjs

In react stock quote data is pulled from an api which returns JSON and I can get the JSON displayed in my react app.

How can I convert the JSON data to look like this on my React page:

**Market Summary > T $20.56**

?

All I need to display is "symbol" and "ap".

From the following:

Market Summary >

```json
{
  "symbol": "T",
  "quote": {
    "t": "2022-05-17T20:34:27.427150733Z",
    "ax": "V",
    "ap": 20.56,
    "as": 1,
    "bx": "V",
    "bp": 20.4,
    "bs": 50,
    "c": [
      "R"
    ],
    "z": "A"
  }
}
```

Where should I add the code that was provided in the answer?
(sorry totally new to react)

My code is as follows:

```
state = {
    value: [],
    quotes: []
}

componentDidMount() {
    // axios.get(`http://localhost/php-rest-api/api/getstockprice.php?stock_ticker=GME`)
    //     .then(res => {
    //         const quotes = res.data;
    //         this.setState({ quotes });
    //     })
}

handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
}

handleSubmit(event) {
    const ticker = {
        name: this.state.value
    }
    const url = 'http://localhost/php-rest-api/api/getstockprice.php?stock_ticker=';
    const urlwithticker = url + ticker.name;
    console.log(ticker.name)
    axios.get(urlwithticker)
        .then(res => {
            const quotes = res.data;
            this.setState({ quotes });
        })
   // alert('Stock ticker was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
}

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    Stock > &nbsp;
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </label>
            </form>
            {console.log(this.state.quotes)}
            Market Summary > &nbsp;
            <div><pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.quotes, null, 2) }</pre></div>
        </div>
    )
}

displayquotes() {
    var quotestring = JSON.stringify(this.state.quotes, 2);
    var jsonobject = JSON.parse(quotestring);
    console.log(jsonobject['symbol'])
}
```

Comment: show your whole component plz

Comment: added, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work.

```js
state = {
    value: [],
    quotes: []
}

componentDidMount() {
    // axios.get(`http://localhost/php-rest-api/api/getstockprice.php?stock_ticker=GME`)
    //     .then(res => {
    //         const quotes = res.data;
    //         this.setState({ quotes });
    //     })
}

handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
}

handleSubmit(event) {
    const ticker = {
        name: this.state.value
    }
    const url = 'http://localhost/php-rest-api/api/getstockprice.php?stock_ticker=';
    const urlwithticker = url + ticker.name;
    console.log(ticker.name)
    axios.get(urlwithticker)
        .then(res => {
            const quotes = res.data;
            this.setState({ quotes });
        })
   // alert('Stock ticker was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
}

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    Stock > &nbsp;
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </label>
            </form>
            Market Summary > {this.state.quotes ? `${this.state.quotes.symbol} $ ${this.state.quotes.quotes.ap}`: 'fetch data'}
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

Please consider learn react again with this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4UZrsTqkcW4)

Comment: Awesome! Got it to work with 1 minor correction (had to change from (quotes.quotes) to  (quotes.quote) = like this:     Market Summary > {this.state.quotes ? `${this.state.quotes.symbol} $ ${this.state.quotes.quote.ap}`: 'fetch data'}

Comment: glad to hear that work. and again. you better learn React again from the tutorial I sent you. // btw you should check this as answer.

Comment: Takashi Anji - great tutorial. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

First you Need to parse your json by using JSON.parser(your_json) after that you can get what you want form json.

Like as you shown above : **Market Summary > T $20.56**

you can retrieve this data like this :

1. Assume that your json came in json varible
2. Now create a varible (assume requiredData) with value empty string.
3. Now set the value to new varible (requiredData) as shown :

```
  let serverJson = json.text();
  let myjson = json.parser(serverJson);
  let requiredData = "";
  
  requiredData = `Market Summary > ${myjson.symbol} $ ${myjson.quote.ap}`
  console.log(requiredData);
```

This is full explanation and code.

Comment: Hi Yogesh, please see my edit above. I added the render code. Where do you suggest I insert your code? Please advise. Thank you!!

Comment: this.handleSubmit is a function and in this function you are make server request to get json. (I think) Now after you get json from server you can insert my code there. Remember that in this line "let serverJson = json.text();" json is your server request json in text form.

Comment: Yogesh, I posted the entire component code. Please advise.